# Raw wiring to a ILI9341 TFT display

Tags: pi-zero, display, spi, lcd

I'm trying to connect a RPi Zero W to a Winstar WF24LTYAJDNN0 LCD module with integrated ILI3941 controller.
The LCD comes with the typical 40 pin flat cable with the following pinout:

[image]

[image]

The LCD is rated 3.3V, 8mA logic current, 80 mA LED current.

[image]

Of course I would like to use the simplest possibile interface mode supported by [fbcp-ili9341](https://github.com/juj/fbcp-ili9341) drivers (3/4 wires SPI AFAIK).

I'm skipping over trivial pins like power pins, NC and DBx pins that should not be used in such i/f mode(s).

The first question is: which i/f type I should select? 3 wire or 4 wire? There are two possibile configuration of IMx pins to select mode and I would like to avoid overlapping error possibilities....

Reading some answers here and there and [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-2-4-color-tft-touchscreen-breakout/pinouts) Adafruit guide I found a partial solution:

- I guess CS (LCD pin 10) can be connected to CE0 (RPi pin 24),
- I guess SCL (LCD pin 11) can be connected to SCLK (RPi pin 23),
- I guess RESET (LCD pin 30) can be connected to GPIO28 (RPi pin 13),
- I guess LEDKx (LCD pin 36, 37) should be connected to ground trough a NPN transistor driven by GPIO18 (RPi pin 12),
- I guess LEDA (LCD pin 38) should be connected to 3.3V (trough a current limiter resistor)..

Now... what about these pins?

- WR (LCD pin 12) should be connected to GPIO25 (RPi pin 22) ??
- RD (LCD pin 13) should be connected to 3.3V ??
- SDA (LCD pin 39) should be connected to RPi MOSI (RPi pin 19) ??

RPi IO levels are 3.3V .. correct?

Can RPi Zero 3.3V output source 90 mA to feed LCD backlight?

Best regards,
Mike

Comment: What data came with your purchase?

Comment: this datasheet is all I have:
https://www.winstar.com.tw/uploads/files/7e32335cb525e5d84865ce353e420c85.pdf

Comment: Don't expect anyone to download a pdf file to work out what you bought. If the data doesn't explain what you need to connect we don't know either. If you only have a downloadable pdf you should copy relevant info into your question.

Comment: @Milliways I'm waiting for more detailed docs from the provider... right now the only thing I can update is the pinout with a more detailed table